# Parsing html in with BeautifulSoup fails to find a table

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse the data in this website:
http://www.baseball-reference.com/boxes/CHN/CHN201606020.shtml

I want to extract some of the data in the tables. But for some reason, I am struggling to find them. For example, what I want to do is this

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'http://www.baseball-reference.com/boxes/CHN/CHN201606020.shtml'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text)
soup.find('table', id='ChicagoCubsbatting')
```

The final line returns nothing despite a table with that id existing in the html. Furthermore, `len(soup.findAll('table'))` returns 1 even though there are many tables in the page. I've tried using the 'lxml', 'html.parser' and 'html5lib'. All behave the same way.

What is going on? Why does this not work and what can I do to extract the table?

Comment: That table is inside of a comment, so it's not actually part of the document.

Comment: Then how does it show up in the webpage? And even so, how can I extract it?

Answer (score 1):

use `soup.find('div', class_='placeholder').next_sibling.next_sibling` to get the comment text, then build a new `soup` using those text.

```
In [35]: new_soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'lxml')

In [36]: new_soup.table
Out[36]: 
<table class="teams poptip" data-tip="San Francisco Giants at Atlanta Braves">
<tbody>
<tr class="winner">
<td><a href="/teams/SFG/2016.shtml">SFG</a></td>
<td class="right">6</td>
<td class="right gamelink">
<a href="/boxes/ATL/ATL201606020.shtml">Final</a>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="loser">
<td><a href="/teams/ATL/2016.shtml">ATL</a></td>
<td class="right">0</td>
<td class="right">
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table
```

Comment: This works, but can anyone explain how/why the commented out table ends up rendered in the browser but not from BeautifulSoup?

Comment: @dillon It's JavaScript